# Compiling Java program in terminal causes log error

Tags: java, ubuntu, logging, terminal, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a Java program in the terminal:

Long version containing all the imports:

```
javac -classpath bin:$OSPL_HOME/jar/dcpssaj5.jar:$OSPL_HOME/jar/dcpssaj5-sources.jar:$OSPL_HOME/jar/dcpssaj-osgi-bundle.jar:$OSPL_HOME/jar/dcpssaj-sources.jar:$OSPL_HOME/jar/dcpssaj.jar:$OSPL_HOME/jar/osplconf.jar:$OSPL_HOME/jar/tooling_common.jar:$OSPL_HOME/jar/dcpsprotobuf.jar:$OSPL_HOME/jar/cmdataadapter.jar:$OSPL_HOME/jar/cmapi.jar:$OSPL_HOME/jar/ddsface.jar:Libraries/httpclient-4.5.12.jar:Libraries/jersey-client-1.19.4.jar:Libraries/jersey-client-1.19.jar:Libraries/jersey-core-1.19.4.jar:Libraries/json-simple-1.1.1.jar:Libraries/json-simple-3.1.0.jar:Libraries/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:Libraries/mqtt-client-0.0.6.jar:Libraries/paho-mqtt-client-1.13.0.jar -sourcepath src/ src/afarcloud/Main/afarcloud_main.java
```

Without all the imports:

```
javac -classpath bin:(jar_files) -sourcepath src/ src/afarcloud/Main/afarcloud_main.java
```

I have added what I thought would be all the necessaries jars, however I get the following error related to a logger when I try to run the code on my Ubuntu computer:

```
src/afarcloud/Log/UtilLog.java:3: error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
                       ^
src/afarcloud/Log/UtilLog.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UtilLog.class);
                   ^
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class UtilLog
src/afarcloud/Log/UtilLog.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UtilLog.class);
                                ^
  symbol:   variable Logger
  location: class UtilLog
src/afarcloud/Log/UtilLog.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        log = Logger.getLogger(clase);
              ^
  symbol:   variable Logger
  location: class UtilLog
4 errors
```

What confuses me is that there is no folder called "Log" under src/afarcloud, so I am pretty confused about how to proceed... Any help is highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks that you're missing import statement. As a conclusion, all Logger Objects cannot be find and any new instances cant be created.

Try to use `import org.apache.log4j.Logger;`.

Or import via CLI. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html

Comment: Hello, thanks. I suspected so, however I am unsure of where to put the import statement as I am not very familiar with Java. To the best of my knowledge I would have to put the import statement in ```src/afarcloud/Log/UtilLog.java```, which I am unable to find. Do you know where I would have to put it, or is it perhaps impossible to say from the provided information?

Comment: That is not the location you need.

Usally, the import statement is needed in the class where you use "Logger". I guess /Log/UtilLog.java is automatically created, because you try to use the class "Logger".

That is why you usally use dependency manager like maven or gradle. Are you familiar with this topic?

Comment: I see, that makes sense. As I didn't write the code myself and it is quite a lot, it seems futile to try to find out where to add the imports. 
I am not familiar with this topic no, as I have never used Java before, but after spending quite some time trying to find a solution, I have heard about Maven. I guess I will have to try it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing JAR dependency on org.apache.log4j.

Of course, this JAR can have further dependencies. This can be endless game. Perhaps you can use Maven and mavenized project, which will take care of dependency tree for you.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I hoped I could avoid getting into all of that as Java is just a tiny part of my project, but it might be a good idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mentioning the jar files of a directory individually, you should use wildcard character `*` to specify all jars of the directory e.g.

```
javac -d bin -cp .:$OSPL_HOME/jar/*:Libraries/*:lib/* -sourcepath src src/afarcloud/Main/afarcloud_main.java
```

where

1. `-d bin` specifies the directory where the compiled class will be put.
2. `.` with `-cp` or `-classpath` includes the current directory in the classpath.
3. `:` specifies the separator to use multiple locations in the classpath.
4. `$OSPL_HOME/jar/*` specifies all the files in the directory, `$OSPL_HOME/jar`. Alternatively, you can use `$OSPL_HOME/jar/*.jar` to specify just jar files.

**Note:** Make sure you also specify the location of the `apache-logging-log4j.jar` in your command because the error shows that you have missed to include this jar.